# Java not a statement error at i < j

Tags: java

When trying to compile a class, I am getting the following error;

```
ExcelReportServlet.java:341: error: not a statement
/* 302 */     for (Iterator localIterator = keyset.iterator();localIterator.hasNext(); i < j)

                                                                                         ^
1 error
```

The particular code is as follows;

```
int j;
int i;
for (Iterator localIterator = keyset.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); i < j)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help...

Comment: Syntax error on token "<", invalid AssignmentOperator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `(i<j)` is a condition that controls the termination of the for loop, it should be in the second part of the for statement.

For example (not sure if that's the required logic) :

```
for (Iterator localIterator = keyset.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext() && i < j;)
```

Answer (score 3):

`i < j` is not a *StatementExpression*. And according to [JLS(§14.14)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14), the rightmost part of for loop is defined as [ForUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ForUpdate) which is in return a [StatementExpressionList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpressionList) (a list of [StatementExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression)).

Answer (score 0):

One of the for sintax is `for(declaration; condition; statement)` where the third argument must be a statement that will be executed in each loop.

In your case, the third argument is a condition (i is lower than j). This is the reason for you compile error. It should be like `for (Iterator localIterator = keyset.iterator();localIterator.hasNext() && i < j)`